# End-to-end testing of Static Web App behind EasyAuth?

Tags: azure, testing, azure-static-web-app

I have an Angular webapp hosted in Static Web Apps and running behind EasyAuth with an AAD provider. I'm looking for suggestions and best practices as to how to do end-to-end testing as I'm struggling with the authentication. I want to setup a Playwright project to do the testing but I cannot log in using the normal login flow as I don't want to rely on a test-user and password (also because of MFA). My thinking was to authenticate using a managed identity of some sort but this is where I run into issues.

I can see that the EasyAuth uses the `StaticWebAppsAuthCookie` but is there any way to retrieve that programmatically without following the normal auth flow and using a managed identity? Or is this the wrong approach and if so what would be a best practise?